# Find drupal logged in users friends on Facebook

Tags: facebook, drupal-6

I have a Drupal website. When a user logs in to my website with his FB account, I need to show his friends who are already a part of the Drupal website or else bring all his friends from FB to the Drupal website and just show their images in a block. Is there any Drupal module already available or any Facebook API I have to use for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Drupal For Facebook](http://drupalforfacebook.org) for this. Or it can be done by javascript sdk also. Call `Fb.api('/me/friends', {fields: age, birthday..}, access_token="ACCESS_TOKEN")` etc.